# unresolved reference 'Intent' : val intent = Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, kotlin

I am sure there is something obvious but have not been able to find a solution to this simple problem. The error is in a main activity attempting to start another activity when a user guesses the correct answer:

> Error:(85, 23) Unresolved reference: Intent

The code is from the High/Low Android app in the book 'Kotlin Development for Android'.

```
val intent = Intent("com.example.user.highlow2.CorrectGuessActivity")
startActivity(intent)
```

The manifest has the following intent-filter for the called activity:

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="com.example.user.highlow2.CorrectGuessActivity"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
</intent-filter>
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The original syntax and suggestions all yielded the same error. The MainActivity needs the following for the Intent to be recognized:
     import android.content.Intent

Comment: Yes, @tomN is correct. importing android.content.Intent will do the job.
At least on my end. 
Thanks man!

Answer (score 1):

Please keep it simple as possible use

```
val intent = Intent(this,CorrectGuessActivity::class.java)
startActivity(intent)
```

Comment: Error:(91, 10) Unresolved reference: Intent, thinking the problem is not with the syntax in the suggested code but maybe with the import statements:

Comment: if you have activities with proper name you don't get error with import statements

Comment: the error was the word 'Intent' in each of the code variations that I tried. It finally went away when I realized that I needed to add an import statement for android.content.intent. thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Intent intent = new Intent (mainActivity.this, secondActivity.class);

startActivity(intent);

Comment: getting same build error: Error:(91, 10) Unresolved reference:

Comment: I updated the answer to be more clear. In java you need to declare the type of variables and then give it a name. Not like with python where you just declare all variables as val

Answer (score 0):

it's import issue, just add this line above the class:
import android.content.Intent